# Верна ли постановка запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли платить за замену неисправного старого оборудования, читайте здесь по ссылке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Союз-частица `ли` говорит о том, что перед нами сложноподчиненное предложение, где `Нужно ли платить за замену неисправного старого оборудования` является придаточной частью.

Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>

> §115. (...) Придаточная часть в сложноподчиненном предложении выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, если стоит внутри главной части; если же **придаточная часть стоит перед главной частью** или после нее, то отделяется от нее запятой.

Соответственно, постановка запятой корректна:

`Нужно ли платить за замену неисправного старого оборудования, читайте здесь по ссылке.`

А еще можно поставить знак тире:

> §124. В сложноподчиненном предложении может ставиться тире:
>
> 1) после придаточной части, стоящей перед главной частью.

`Нужно ли платить за замену неисправного старого оборудования — читайте здесь по ссылке.`

Я бы поспорил насчет формулировки `здесь по ссылке`. Контент находится либо здесь, либо не здесь (тогда надо перейти по ссылке).

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.